# Pagination on php array and calling it to html

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, pagination

I've read about pagination on arrays and I know there are already tutorials about it but I guess I have a different problem. I have a `view.php` which contains the code for array which is from the database, and it is encoded as `json` array. When you open with browser the view it shows the array but what I did was I connected my `index.html` to my `javascript`. I append the values from `view.php`. I check if `tbody` is empty and I append the data if it is empty. Now my problem is I don't know how can I do the pagination. I don't know if I'm going to put it on `view.php` or `index.html` or on the `javascript`. And I don't know how will I be able to do the pagination because I did different process with `json` encoding.

**view.php**

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` order by datetime desc";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$result = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    array_push($result, array('name' => $row[0],'username' => $row[1]));

    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result ));
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
        <tr class = "active" >
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- RETRIEVE DATABASE THROUGH javascript -->       
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
function updates() {
    $.getJSON("view.php", function(data){

        $("tbody").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function(){

            $("tbody").append("<tr class = 'active'><td align = 'center'>"+this['username']+
            "</td><td align = 'center'>"+this['name'] )
        });
    });
}
```

By the way, I used `javascript` because I want to automatically update the data once there is an additional record on the database.

Comment: *(Personally)* I would do all the calculations on the `php` page and include the details inside your returning array similar to: `echo json_encode(array("result" => $result,"count"=>count($result),"range_from"=>1,"range_to"=>5,"limit"=>5));`....etc. All the pagination details can be easily figured out server-side and passed to your javascript.

Comment: Thank you! Now, I am able to know how much records I have. But how will I be able to put on a button?

Comment: well, just like the `data.result`, you should be able to do a `data.whatever` to access those values.